# Четные/нечетные числа из двумерного массива.Си

Tags: c++, c, массивы, память

Задание:

С помощью динамического распределения памяти создать двумерный массив 10 х 10, заполненный случайными значениями от -100 до 100. Создать два одномерных массива с первоначальной длиной 0. Затем поместить в первый массив элементы с четным значением, во второй с нечетным.Размер одномерных массивов при добавлении увеличивается на единицу.

Вывод: Двумерный массив и два одномерных.

Код работает спасибо Andrej Levkovitch за подробное разъяснение!

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define d 10

int Outputodnomer(int a[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i)
        printf("%5d", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}


int Outputdvumer(int *a[d])
{
    printf("Двумерный массив:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < d; ++j) {
            printf("%4d", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
int odnomer(int *a[d], int mas1[], int mas2[]) {
    int k = 0, n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < d; ++j) {
            if (a[i][j] % 2 != 0) {
                mas1[k] = a[i][j];
                k++;
            }
            else {
                mas2[n] = a[i][j];
                n++;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;

}

int Generation(int *a[d])
{
    int i, j;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < d; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < d; ++j) {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 200 - 101;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int i, **mas=  { 0 } , *mas1 = { 0 }, *mas2 = { 0 },s;

    mas = (int**)malloc(10 * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
        mas[i] = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    mas1 = (int*)malloc(d*d * sizeof(int));
    mas2 = (int*)malloc(d*d * sizeof(int));

    Generation(mas);
    Outputdvumer(mas);
    odnomer(mas, mas1, mas2);
    for (i = 0;i < 10;++i)
        free(mas[i]);
    free(mas);
    printf("Одномерный массив с нечетными числами: \n");
    Outputodnomer(mas1);
    free(mas1);
    printf("Одномерный массив с четными числами: \n");
    Outputodnomer(mas2);
    free(mas2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Из функции `int Generation(int **a, int c1, int c2)` Вы хотите получить значения `c1` и `c2`? А вот не получите - параметры передаются по значению, а не по ссылке. Нужно передавать указатели. Думаю, это и есть причина досрочной остановки программы. 2. В `Generation()` Вы неверно считаете `c1` - оно будет увеличиваться и вместе с `c2`. Видимо, там предполагался блок `else`.

Comment: а кто будет уничтожать обьекты из динамической памяти?

Comment: https://ideone.com/B7MArO

Comment: Нужно привести [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), который воспроизводит проблему. Попробуйте запускать код по одной строке и проверять запуститься ли. Приведите минимальный код на котором ошибка воспроизведется.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Первое:

```
mas = (int**)malloc(d * sizeof(int*));
for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    mas[i] = (int*)malloc(d * sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<d;i++)
            free(mas[i]);
    free(mas);
```

Тут Вы выделяете память, и тут же освобождаете её.

Второе: области видимости

```
int odnomer(int **a, int c1, int c2) {
  int *mas1,*mas2;
  int k = 0;
  mas1 = (int*)malloc(d*d * sizeof(int));
  mas2 = (int*)malloc(d*d * sizeof(int));
```

Здесь, Вы выделяете память под массивы, которые объявлены в этой функции, а не в main.

Третье:

```
for (i = 0; i < d; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < d; ++j)
        a[i][j] = rand() % 200 - 101;
        if (a[i][j] % 2 == 0)
            c2++;
        c1++;
```

Пропущены фигурные скобки. Циклы выполняют всего один оператор.
Чтобы выполнить более одного оператора нужно поместить их в блок кода (фигурные скобки)

Четвертое:

```
int Outputdvumer(int **a)
{
  printf("Двумерный массив:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i) 
    for (int j = 0; j < d; ++j)
        printf("%8d", a[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Вы передали указатель на указатель на `int`, но как программма должна понять, что это массив `int` размера 10 на 10?
Для этого надо передать так:

```
int Outputdvumer(int *a[d])
```

Возможно, Вам не нужно динамическое выделение памяти? 
У вас массивы имеют статические размеры.

Вот подправленный рабочий код (хотя он весьма грубый):

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#define d 10

int Outputodnomer(int a[]) {
    printf("array\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i)
        printf("%4d", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}


int Outputdvumer(int a[][d])
{
    printf("Array:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < d; ++j) {
            printf("%4d", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
int odnomer(int a[][d], int mas1[], int mas2[]) {
    int k = 0, n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < d; ++j) {
            if (a[i][j] % 2 != 0) {
                mas1[k] = a[i][j];
                k++;
            }
            else {
                mas2[n] = a[i][j];
                n++;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;

}

int Generation(int a[][d])
{
    int i, j;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < d; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < d; ++j) {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 200 - 101;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
int main() 
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int mas[d][d] = {{0}}, mas1[d*d] = {0}, mas2[d*d] = {0};

    Generation(mas);
    Outputdvumer(mas);
    odnomer(mas, mas1, mas2);
    Outputodnomer(mas1);
    Outputodnomer(mas2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Будем надеяться, что этот ответ, для которого вы уделили столько времени, поможет Семену в учебе.

Comment: Вы уверены, что код рабочий? Каким компилятором? Покажите строчку компиляора.

Comment: andrej@H81M-S1 ~/Public/example $ gcc -o 2 2.cpp -Wall
andrej@H81M-S1 ~/Public/example $ ./2
Array:
  39 -15 -70   0 -38  67  98  71-101  61
   8 -72  42  63  -3 -16 -42  27 -12 -46
 -23  28 -68  59   8  13  89 -42  76 -52
  19  16  34   3  69  97 -77  20  21  75
 -18  82 -96  77  -1   2 -38  58  82   3
  65 -88  84  98  72 -55 -35  14   4 -58
  63  77  11 -50 -67 -19-100 -43  54  23
  85  89 -42  90  67  58 -55  82  18  80
 -62 -64  45 -77  88  18 -31 -46  85  27
  -3   2   5  61  53  39 -57   7  49  50
array
  39 -15  67  71-101  61  63  -3  27 -23
array
 -70   0 -38  98   8

Comment: @0xdb пришлось укоротить, но, как видите, код рабочий - я даже перепроверил.

Comment: Да, но вы его скомпилировали как c++. Зачем тогда писать - "Это ж c"?

Comment: @0xdb а с каких это пор `gcc` - это с++?

Comment: @0xdb я для кого вывод предоставлял?

Comment: Всегда так было. Вы же расширение дали 2.cpp. Попробуйте переименовать в 2.c.

Comment: @0xdb а, ну да, про это я подзабыл. Но дела это не меняет: все что нужно, это просто переименовать заголовочные файлы на соответствущее `cи`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch "ТС ведь собки даже не поставил в циклах" Это вопрос код стайла, скобки там необязательны.

Comment: @Suvitruf, в Generation обязательны

Comment: @vp_arth хм, не заметил. Там действительно нужно.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Хотел именно с динамическим выделением памяти написать

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Вопрос есть такой, у нас в первой функции в цикле i<d, тем самым четных и нечетных чисел не будет больше 10, хотя их в сумме 100. Как записать все нужные числа в одномерные массивы?

Comment: @Семен Вы про outptodnomer? Эта функция выводит содержимое массива на экран и никакого отношения к его элементам не имеет. В этих массивах содержаться все элементы изначального массива, просто выводятся только первые 10.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Да, верно. Но как сделать, чтобы выводились все четные и нечетные, а не только по 10?

Comment: @Семён просто вывести оба массива полностью.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch То есть не выводить через одну функцию оба массива, а выводить отдельно?

Comment: Если не трудно, можно пример?

Comment: @Семён все этой же функцией: просто сделайте так, чтобы она выводила массив целиком (который в этом конкретном случае имеет размер 100 элементов)